# how to control jinja loop using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, jinja2

I am trying to make something like a todolist web with flask, and I am inserting new tasks using a jinja loop in index.html

```
{% for x in data %}
    <div class="love">
        <button type="button" class="tasks" style="background-color: {{x[1]}};">
            {{x[0]}}<i class="{{x[2]}}" id="habitIcons"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

and I've add some javascript code to define clicked buttons by adding a ("clicked") class to them

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    const habitBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("habits");
    const habitBtnsArray = Array.from(habitBtns);
    habitBtnsArray.forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener("click", () => {
            element.setAttribute("class", "clicked");
            element.removeAttribute("style")
            reloadCss()
        });
    })
})
```

the problem is when the window reloads, all the tasks lose there ("clicked") class and it get replaced by the default ("habits") class as you can see in the html code earlier
what can I do to prevent that from happening keep in mind that I use vanilla javascript

I thought of changing the data base but I relised that I am using vanilla javascript.

Comment: You can't do much really. Jinja and JavaScript are two things that cannot interact with each other. It would be helpful to try and explain *why* you would need to do this in the first place, it looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). If you need to remember some state then you can use things like cookies, `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` from JS, and add a bit of JS code that restores the saved classes (if any) from there upon page load. Also note that creating multiple elements with the same ID (`id="habitIcons"`) is invalid.

Comment: thank you very much, I'll try do it with cookies + I already know that this isn't the right way to use an id, but the problem was that when I add two classes to an icon the second one gets deleted for some reason, and I can't use the first one to style all icons because it's a variable, I do know that I can do it via javascript, but I don't think that it's the best practices to do it manually, do you have any clue on how to fix that.

Comment: You are losing classes because of the way you're assigning the new class, `clicked`. You are simply overwriting the current classes with it. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ybgu9pwa/) to understand what's happening. Instead of doing `element.setAttribute`, simply use `element.classList.add("clicked")`. Or, when you need to remove a class: `element.classList.remove("clicked")` .

Comment: thank you but this wasn't my problem, the problem is I can't add more than one class when I generate the buttons in the html code above, all the class will be simply delete, this is what the code looks like {{x[0]}}<i class="{{x[2]}}" class="habitIcons"></i>, and when I run it, it's {{x[0]}}<i class="{{x[2}}"></i>.

Comment: @Hassaneinali *"I can't add more than one class when I generate the buttons in the html code above"* - You can, you are just using the wrong syntax. You should do `{{x[0]}}<i class="{{x[2]}} habitIcons"></i>`. You cannot have multiple `class=` attributes. Put all your classes separated by spaces into a single one.